# Toggle <i> chevron icon via Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Trying to figure out how to toggle a `<i class='chevron-icon-down'>` located in a mobile menu item in an `<li>` tag with a class of .menu-item-has-children.

```js
$('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() {
  $('.menu-item-has-children li a').toggle('1000');
  $("i", this).toggleClass("fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-right");
});
```

```css
.fa-chevron-right {
  content: "\f078";
}

.fa-chevron-down:before {
  content: "\f054";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-101238 has-ul open">
  <a href="#">About
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: `$('.menu-item-has-children li a')` <= this is an incorrect selector.  The first class **is** the li.  The li is not a child.

Comment: good catch so: $('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() {
    $('.menu-item-has-children a').toggle('1000');
    $("i", this).toggleClass("fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-right");
}); ???... Though, it still does not work.

Comment: @taplar I have had some trouble with the child <i> tag of the .menu-item-has-children <li>. I can't make changes to it using jquey. Ex: $( ".fa-chevron-down" ).wrap( "<div id='menu-item-open' class='new'></div>" ); does nothing.

Comment: `$("i", this).toggleClass("fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-righ");` that's a typo right? supposed to be `right` instead of `righ` ?

Comment: Your css is missing before for right `.fa-chevron-right {` should be `.fa-chevron-right:before {` works for me with that css fix and the typo correction on `righ`

Comment: @Huangism yes that's correct. It is a typo. my apologies. Updated code: 

$('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() { 
 $('.menu-item-has-children a').toggle('1000'); 
 $("i", this).toggleClass("fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-right"); 
});

Comment: You can edit the question to correct the typo in the future, I corrected it for you after your confirmation. Anyway, my previous comment solved the issue as far as I can tell

Comment: @Huangism all corrections made still not working.

Comment: @HobartHobieMunsell given the above code with the fixes I mentioned https://jsfiddle.net/fr150jg2/ it works. I changed the symbols to text for clearer view

Comment: @Huangism changing the icon to text string the text doesn't toggle from "down" to "right". still no clear solution. not exactly sure what's causing the issue.

Comment: @HobartHobieMunsell I have no idea what you mean, everything works fine in that fiddle. What browser are you using? try https://jsfiddle.net/7wbsn0t8/1/

Comment: @Huangism yes everything works well in jsfiddle, but when applied to the site I'm currently developing, the supplied code doesn't function properly. There's something breaking the code on the site that's not included in jsfiddle.

Comment: Unless you can reproduce the issue here, there isn't much anyone can do. You can always trace the code and put breakpoints in the js to figure out if things are triggering or not but you would have to do that yourself if you cannot reproduce the issue here

Comment: @Huangism the only thing that gives me pause; is no matter how I try to edit the <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> within the <li> class.menu-item-has-children on the site I manage. I cannot make changes to that element via jquery. Ex: $( ".fa-chevron-down" ).removeClass( "fa fa-chevron-down" ).addClass( "yourClass" );. I have even tried to grab the specific class selector for that single element with the dev browser inspector. No change at all. LOL incredibly frustrating!! LOL

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is already fine except one typo righ(right) but you should add font-awesome css in your code and You don't need to write any extra css for icon classes.**

```js
$('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() {
  $('.menu-item-has-children li a').toggle('1000');
  $("i", this).toggleClass("fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-right");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-101238 has-ul open">
  <a href="#">About
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </a>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The issue is the missing `before` for `.fa-chevron-right {` if typo is the only issue, please vote to close the qustion due to typo

Comment: @Huangism Added the external js/css to my wordpress header.php file. still not working.... also added the :before pseudo to .fa-chevron-right { /// some  code here}  &  fixed toggleClass typo . still not working....??